# Alien Invasion, Military Strategy and Genetic Enhancements

Tags: internal-consistency, biology, super-powers, strategy

(Revised original concept based on feedback)

So, a race of humanoid aliens have invaded and are planning to wipe us out for some reason or another (apparently we offended them somehow), and after a brutal and sudden opening, both humanity and the aliens eventually find themselves locked in a stalemate.

Despite the aliens having some form of interstellar technology, both sides have more or less fought to a draw, since their weapons technology doesn't appear to be much more advanced than our own. However, we have much shorter supply lines, so we can afford to expend a few more drones and missiles than them.

While the worlds various Navy's and Air Forces struggle to keep shipping and flight lanes open and prevent the invaders from taking control of the skies, the ground forces are stuck trying to dislodge what ground forces the aliens managed to land. This is proving difficult as the aliens have settled in for a siege, and their ground-based defence technology is several steps above our own. Primarily, their bases are defended with some sort of select frequency EMP shield and various anti-air and -rocket/missile system that renders them virtually immune to any air-based attack short of a sustained saturation attack to overload their defences.

While the various land forces figure out an optimal strategy to destroy the alien land bases, the aliens themselves begin a campaign of terror strikes targeting various civilian population centers and industry. This is rather effective until they target a laboratory belonging to a rather unremarkable and privately funded genetic research company, the reason being a few leaked pieces of security footage showing several members of the sites security personnel defeating the would be aliens in CQB seemingly unaided.

This causes a bit of a stir worldwide, as the aliens have been noted to have increased levels of physical performance compared to humans, with various critics citing the footage as fake and a propaganda stunt - until the company confirms that it did actually happen.

They go onto explain that they were profiling the aliens genetic material for weakness to various chemical and biological agents, when a researcher discovered several genes that controlled motor unit co-ordination in muscles and tissue recovery for various organs, allowing for more effective healing, essentially borderline organ/soft tissue regeneration. Furthermore, in a nearly impossible genetic fluke, the genes are somehow compatible-more or less, with the human genome, and with a modified retrovirus as a delivery vector, an intensive month-long gene therapy procedure was developed.

Despite various protests, lawsuits and complaints about 'playing God', they defend their research, presenting evidence that modern-day genetic science could have discovered something effectively similar within several decades - or a lucky genetic mutation.

---

I'm primarily interested in the plausibility of the various aspects of my scenario - Is the fact that the aliens, despite being from a much more advanced society, have weapons technology that isn't much more advanced than ours? Would alien forces trapped on the ground resort to terror strikes against civilians to force the governments to reassign military assets to protect them? The fact that a select few parts of their genetic material are essentially somehow compatible with humans, the biological effects of the improvements are plausible, and the duration of the enhancement procedure and the non-alien-influenced development time for said enhancements. I know that the ethical concerns around genetic engineering are real enough - I need only look at the news.

Comment: It's only overkill if significantly less would suffice to get the job done. If whatever amount of whatever is actually needed to achieve the intended goal, then it is not overkill; it is prudence. What is needed to destroy a tank would be overkill against unprotected human targets, but that doesn't mean that if your goal is to destroy the tank using the force it takes to do so is overkill.

Comment: Hello @Seta and welcome to Worldbuilding. Your setting is clear-cut, but your **question** is not. I cannot even locate a question. What is it that you seek to get within potential answers? You should edit your post to clarify what kind of response you are looking for. :)

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors Thanks for the welcome. I've edited my post a bit, so hopefully its a bit clearer now.

Comment: A technological solution worth investigating: exoskeletons. If you can field your troops with the right exo, you could make them stronger, capable to bear heavier weapons and armor, increase athletic capabilities, and inject them with a variety of drugs (antiseptic, performance enhancing...). Pro: 100% humanity preserved, could be worn by anybody regardless of physical condition. Cons: would require training and maintenance, may not quite solve all your problems, could be rather expensive.

Comment: If they have the technology to manipulate living humans, then don't they have the technology to make some underground labs for eggs, sperm, and something to grow them in?

Comment: why would the war take that long?  With current tech +some way to get a lot of material into space, we could put together a fleet that would take a planet in months.  Why would we be able to hold out for years against a stronger enemy that obviously has a lot of practice at this

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, and addressing some of the flaws within my setting. I'll review my setting, and see if I can get a more believable scenario going here that doesn't require too much suspension of (dis)belief to work.

Answer (score 3):

Your question assumes that humans will be going face to face with the enemy, almost like a battle of old where two armies face get set up on opposing ends of a field and then have at each other. That has not really been the case since the 1980's.

Today, a guy in a trailer on the continental US can do more damage to an enemy's armoured forces half-way accross the world with a drone, than can a fully equipped platoon of battle tanks, all while being home in time to tuck his kids in at night and grab a beer, watching some NetFlix. The days when sheer physical strength and resilience mattered are long gone. Nowadays the soft squishy humans are either killed outright, or does not even get a scratch because they are either not on the battlefield, or neatly wrapped up in many layers of protection. The tipping-point between annihilation and complete safety is so thin by now that the factors of which you speak are not really relevant.

**Unless...**

...you set the stage for that. Change the setting so that physical qualities become relevant for war, and then we can tell in more detail how the desired qualities might be achieved.

Comment: I'm tempted to flag this as not an answer. While it's relevant, it makes no attempt to answer the question as asked.

Comment: @Frostfyre Do as you wish with it. This was too much to fit into comments. I personally think the question is much too broad anyway. There is no solid thread to tug at.  :)

Comment: You could vote to close the question as to broad and include your reasoning for doing so in the comments. That would bring it to the attention of the community and possibly start a conversation to help the OP. This is his/her first post, after all.

Comment: Sorry, but you literally said it wasn't a response to the question, and I agree with Frostfyre. Besides, Seta has probably noticed it.

Comment: @XandarTheZenon As I said: do what you want with it, as long as you think it benefits Seta. :)

Comment: While its not a proper answer to my question as such, its still a useful answer as it addresses some of the problems with my setting, which is useful in its own way. And to be fair, my setting as posted probably still isn't very well clarified. I'll take this info into review, and see if I can narrow down a more believable scenario without editing my question too much. If not, I'll close this question and post another, which will hopefully be less broad and more believable.

Comment: @Seta and Michael, a non-answer should never be deliberately posted as an answer, especially when you know for a fact it's not an answer and admit it as such. Seta, you should not encourage non-answers, nor should you post edited duplicates of your question. There's already a feature that will allow you to improve your question. It's called the [edit](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/posts/40174/edit) feature. Michael, go ahead and vote to close if you feel it's too broad, or go ahead and edit your "answer" to be a real answer. Or write a smaller comment that improves the question.

Comment: Ok, are you guys most interested in rules-lawyering or helping the questioner, hm? SE doesn't exist for the benefit of its rules but for its participants. Either flag the question to be closed, or don't. I did what I could with the question without slapping a newcomer with a "Closed - too broad" on their very first question.

Comment: @TheAnathema My understanding of the edit function is that its meant to be used to improve/clarify the question. If I end up redoing my whole scenario to the point where it is technically a new question, shouldn't it deserve a new question instead of shifting the goalposts on this question?

Comment: @MichaelKarnerfors SE isn't for open conversation about a topic. It's a Q&A site, and by adhering to the standards you're helping the questioner the most. Right now we're trying to hold higher standards for questions and answers and nail down the scope of the site. By setting a precedent for "This isn't an answer but let's talk about it like buds" we're opening ourselves up to a whole can of worms I don't want to open. I'm all for helping OP, which is why I'm recommending that you vote instead of having a conversation. You said it was broad/unclear but you didn't vote to close.

Comment: @Seta Yes, that's correct. But if you're just making it less broad, editing it is better.

Comment: Post changed so that it is an answer to the question as it is presently stated. If there is anything else you wish for me to know about how to make SE a high quality site where people get the help they need for their world-building, do not hesitate to enlighten me. Thank you for the conversation. :)